# Integrating a specific function

Tags: integration

I'm struggling to integrate. Can anyone help?

$$\int \frac{1}{1+\sqrt{x+1}}dx$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1):

Try the substitution:
$$u^2 = x+1, \ x= u^2 -1$$
$$dx = 2u \ du$$
Your integral then simplifies to:

$$\int \frac{2u}{u + 1}\ du$$

Can you finish it from here?

Comment: Yes, thank you so much

Comment: You're welcome!